Faced someone with
Is it okay to say that someone faces someone with their destiny, for example, to make them deal with something difficult?

Can you give some more details of the situation? I think you want something like "force someone to face their destiny" but not sure that's the meaning you actually want.

I mean to confront with and I'm not sure I can use "face" instead

You confront someone with negative things (uncomfortable truths, evidence of their imperfections or sins, sins, etc.), More neutrally, you present them with facts, predictions, etc. We don't normally use to face "ditransitively" where the direct object is a person being given "problematic information" as an indirect object.

To rephrase that, "faced with" usually refers to something that happens to you, not something someone does to you. "I was faced with a problem, but I solved it."

Not unless you're the Ghost of Christmas Yet to Come, or somebody like that. And confront is a better word…unless you're a demigod, at least.

No, this is not an idiomatically common pattern. If Person A wishes to force Person B to consider hard facts (C), we might say:

Person A was faced with the C
Person B made Person B face the C
... or any of a selection of verbs that suits the transitive need: B confronted A with C, set C before A, "held A's nose to the grindstone" until they dealt with C, etc.


There are various examples where 'face someone with [noun {phrase}]' are idiomatic, but often the with-phrase is subject-orientated:


he faced him with surprising courage [Reddit]

he faced him with a blank look [facebook]

he faced him with a glare of defiance [E F Stearns, Technical World Magazine]

he faced him with a spear [bay12forums]



Examples where the noun phrase is something the direct object referent is faced [up] (confronted) / presented with are rarer and usually with a restricted subset of logically suitable noun phrases, usually an obvious challenge or obviously challenging situation:


he faced him with the challenge to give up [his] earthly riches [St Peter's Pastoral
Area]

he faced him with the terrifying spectre of the Ghost of Marley [CIA.gov]

he faced him with fastballs [Detroit News]



But making someone face their destiny/future is probably not seen as such a direct challenge. Whether it is or not, Google ngrams for 'made him face his destiny' and 'made him face his future' both flatline.
There are similarly few (though not no) examples of 'face him with an opportunity', 'face him with an offer', and 'face him with a choice' on the internet. Where 'face someone with a choice' is used, it is usually not a choice one likes to make.
